# On click function from a loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP array containing Ids and names ages, I want while I am looping through that array echo out the age inside a div with onClick event, that function should display once clicked the name of the element in the loop, My problem is that after displaying all these Divs and choose one to click on, it shows only the name of the last Div in the array.

**My code**:

```
foreach($output as $data => $values) {
    $age = $values['age'];
    $name = $values['name']; ?> 

    <article class="<?php echo rand(9999,9999999); ?>">
        <script>
            name= "<?php echo $name ;?>";
        </script>
        <?php echo "<p class= '".rand(9,8889)."'><div class= '".rand(1,888)."' onClick= 'bringName(name)'>".$age."</div></p>"; ?>
        <div class="detailed" id="<?php echo rand(99,9999); ?>">

        </div><!--/ .detailed-->
    </article> <!--/ .article-->
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>    
    function bringName(varx){
        var vacc = varx;
        alert(vacc);
        //e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you have a typo at the <script> tag, you hae two closed </script> tag

Comment: Why are you using `rand()` to generate classes/ids? I don't see why that would be necessary or even useful at all

Comment: `onClick= 'bringName` and `function callme` ...you haven't even shown us two pieces of related code. Where's your "bringName" function?

Comment: #ADson all divs contains differents users names , but on click they all alert the last div's name

Comment: That code really need to be formatted so it is readable.

Comment: @findAffs I already know that, and it has nothing to do with what I wrote in my comment. But I see you edited it to make a bit more sense, so thankyou. I also wrote an explanation of your problem and a simple solution to it - see my answer below. P.S. If you want to tag someone, use the @ character (not #) and then start typing the name, and select it from the popup. I saw your comment only because I was still writing the answer when it appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got pretty complicated code, but I think what you want is to send an `alert()` containing the name when you click it. Try this:

```
<script>
    function bringName(varx) {
        var vacc = varx
        alert(vacc);
    }
</script>

<?php
    foreach($output as $data => $values) {
        $age = $values['age'];
        $name = $values['name']; ?>

        <article>
            <p>
                <div 
                    onclick="bringName(this.dataset.name)" 
                    data-name="<?= $name ?>">
                        <?= $age ?>
                </div>
            </p>
            <div class="detailed">

            </div>
        </article>
```

This utilizes [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), and can directly replace all the code in your question.

I think this solution is cleaner than concatenating the string into the function call by PHP, and it uses native JavaScript.

Comment: @findAffs Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

`bringName(name)`

This will send the value of a JS variable called `name` into the bringName function...but you're setting `name` as a global JS variable in the `<script>` tags you output. Trouble is, this means you print some JS to set the `name` variable, and this code, not being part of a function, executes immediately when the page loads.

So immediately it runs `name="[whatever]"` as many times as you had values in `$output` in your PHP (because you created that number of `name=` statements. Obviously, this means only the last value in the last statement survives the process. By the time you click on anything, it uses the value of `name` it finds at that moment in time, which of course is the last one.

It's a logical error, with a fairly simple solution: you don't need the `name` value in your JS at all.

Just write

```
onClick= 'bringName(\"".$name."\")'
```

in your PHP, to hard-code the value into each onClick you create.